# Not able to Fetch data, Using where clause to the result of union clause

Tags: sql, oracle

I Need to fetch data form two tables from the result i get from union clause and to the result i have one more where clause added

```
select * from (select a.empid,a.department from EMPLOYEE a
union
select b.empid,b.empname from employeedetails b) t where  a.empid=1;
```

I am getting this error.[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`a` is not defined in the outer query.  `t` is:

```
where t.empid = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

This `UNION` won't do what you want because you are mixing different columns.
In your case the result of your query will be 2 rows where in the 1st row you will have the employee's id and the department and in the 2nd row the employee's id and name.
What you need is a join:

```
select e.empid, e.department, d.empname 
from EMPLOYEE e inner join employeedetails d
on d.empid = e.empid
where e.empid = 1
```